# wait for multiple queues in python

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, gevent

How to implement logic of following go code in python  using any concurrency libraries like asyncio or gevent.

```
messages := make(chan string)
signals := make(chan bool)
for{
  select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    case sig := <-signals:
        fmt.Println("received signal", sig)
  }
}
```

in python, i will be having queues instead of channels. i want to wait until any of queue has item to get and do some actions after retrieving the item.